# Counting the total items in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to bring the total items from this system
[image: System Info]

and retrieve it in a query.

Problem is the system doesn't automatically have a column for total items.

My code looks like this:

```
(case when mu.master_unit_no is not null then
count(mu.master_unit_no) 
end)
as 'Total M#s',


(case when mu.master_unit_no is null then
count(c.serial_no) 
end)
as 'Total Serials'
```

But outputs this:

[image: Query Result]

How can I get it to look the same as what's in the system.

(Ideally I want to combine the two columns so that it reads 4 for 'Total Items')

Outbound Case No: M#

License Plate No: Serial

Answer (score 0):

You would have added `master_unit_no` in `Group by` but it should not. If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
count(case when mu.master_unit_no is not null then mu.master_unit_no end) as 'Total M#s',
count(case when mu.master_unit_no is null then c.serial_no end) as 'Total Serials'
```

Comment: im getting 20 under m# now and 3 under serial.  half the problem is fixed i just need to only show 1 for m#.